# SQLite INSTEAD OF TRIGGER

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, triggers

I want to convert this Microsoft SQL Server trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_EliminoItems]
ON [dbo].[PedidosEncabezado]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into HistPedidosEncabezado select * from PedidosEncabezado where PedidosID in ( select PedidosID from deleted )
    insert into HistPedidosItems select * from PedidosItems where PedidosID in ( select PedidosID from deleted )

    delete from PedidosItems where PedidosID in ( select PedidosID from deleted )
    delete from PedidosEncabezado where PedidosID in ( select PedidosID from deleted )

END
```

into SQLite.

Comment: And what is your problem with this trigger? That SQLite has no `SET` statement, or anything else?

Comment: I´m trying to create the same sql trigger in sqlite but it seems that sqlite does´t allow to create triggers in tables only in views. Is that right?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), that's right, but only for `INSTEAD OF` triggers.

Comment: Please check the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not allow `INSTEAD OF` triggers on tables, but you were going to delete those records anyway:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_EliminoItems
BEFORE DELETE ON PedidosEncabezado
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO HistPedidosEncabezado
      SELECT * FROM PedidosEncabezado WHERE PedidosID = OLD.PedidosID;
    INSERT INTO HistPedidosItems
      SELECT * FROM PedidosItems      WHERE PedidosID = OLD.PedidosID;
    DELETE FROM PedidosItems          WHERE PedidosID = OLD.PedidosID;
END;
```